# Manage the entire body in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component manages the entire app in react. It looks like:

```
var Page = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Page',

    render: function() {
        return (
            React.DOM.div(null
                /*, stuff here ..*/
            )
        );
    }
});
```

And html looks like

```
<body id="content"></body>
```

And I render it like:

```
React.renderComponent(Page(null), document.getElementById('content'));
```

But instead, I would like react to manage the entire `body` tag, so there is no redundant nested `div`. How can I render such a thing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you're asking, but you can run

```
React.renderComponent(Page(null), document.body);
```

to mount a component directly into body.

Comment: I'm trying to mount the `body` instead of mounting _into_ the body

Comment: Ah, I see. Currently full-page rendering (including managing the `body` tag from React) is supported only when the entire page markup is generated by React in a server context (using react-page, for instance): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/4jI5xe7TXzQ/3sjSBbpDpEwJ.